# PHP Warning: preg_match() expects & PHP Warning: strip_tags()

Tags: php

I got this error log, do you know what is this and how can i fix this?

```
[31-Jan-2013 22:01:25 UTC] PHP Warning:  preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in /home/xxx/public_html/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 608
[31-Jan-2013 22:01:25 UTC] PHP Warning:  strip_tags() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /home/xxx/public_html/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 968
```

Comment: It's an error message and it tells you what the problem is and where the error was raised. As you can see from your tag (php), it's off topic here and belongs to SO (as long as you can't tell why this is a WP problem and doesn't only happen in it's context). Flagged for moving.

Comment: I think WordPress specific debugging is on topic enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `remove_accents()` and `sanitize_title_with_dashes()` with an array as first argument somewhere. This is wrong, use a string instead.

Install the  [Debug Bar](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/debug-bar/) plugin and look at the backtrace to see where the broken code starts.

Comment: xx.server.com #3, PHP 5.3.18, MySQL 5.1.65, Memory Usage 17,024,752 bytes, TOTAL WARNINGS: 0 , TOTAL NOTICES: 1 (NOTICE: wp-includes/locale.php:257 - Undefined index: 00), should I look somthing else?

Comment: Yes, at the debug_backtrace you get when an error occurs.

Comment: where is debug_backtrace?

Comment: When an error occurs Debug Bar will offer a separate tab with detailed information about that error, especially where it comes from. That’s the backtrace.